# Tensorflow: Get largest entries of 4D tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, semantic-segmentation

I have a tensor named "labels" of shape [-1, 256, 256, 10] which includes labeled images of size 256x256 from which I get the three largest entries of the last dimension with "tf.math.top_k".

Now I want to extract the three largest entries and make it each a tensor of shape [-1,256,256,1] to show it as an image in tensorboard.

The code seems to work, only it doesn't give me the largest entries of EACH batch but only of the last element in the batch.

```
Y = tf.placeholder_with_default(targets, shape=None, name="label")
labels = tf.reshape(Y, [-1, 256, 256, 10])
hot_labels = tf.reduce_max(labels,(1,2),keepdims=True)

top3_val,top3_idx = tf.nn.top_k(hot_labels,3)
top3_idx = tf.transpose(tf.squeeze(top3_idx))

top_labels0 = tf.gather(labels,top3_idx[0,-1],axis=-1)
top_labels0 = tf.reshape(top_labels0,[-1,256,256,1])

top_labels1 = tf.gather(labels,top3_idx[1,-1],axis=-1)
top_labels1 = tf.reshape(top_labels1,[-1,256,256,1])

top_labels2 = tf.gather(labels,top3_idx[2,-1],axis=-1)
top_labels2 = tf.reshape(top_labels2,[-1,256,256,1])
```

The endgoal is to find the three largest last entries of "labels" and show them in tensorflow each as a image of size [-1,256,256,1].

Comment: Are you sure the labels shape is (256,256,10)? It is a bit strange.

Comment: Thanks for asking. The labels shape is (?,256,256,10) because of semantic segmentation where the last dimension is used as 10 classes.